# Why doesn't this javascript code work?

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunction(messager) {
    this.message = messager;
}
new myFunction("Hello");
document.write(myFunction.message);
```

Comment: `myFunction.message` works if you write `myFunction.message = 'Hello'` instead of `new ....`. But there is really no point in doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were trying to reference a member of the function object itself, which is totally incorrect.

When using `this` in conjunction with the `new` keyword, `this` will refer to the object instance which is implicitly returned from the constructor function.

This code should work:

```
function myFunction(messager) {
    this.message = messager;
}
var obj = new myFunction("Hello");
document.write(obj.message);
```

You can also use the `prototype` member to augment member functions and variables onto the created objects:

```
myFunction.prototype.doSomething = function() {
   alert('Hello ' + this.message);
}

obj.doSomething(); //alerts "Hello Hello"
```

Answer (score 3):

The `new` keyword causes `this` to refer to the **instance of the object** and not to the **constructor function**.

```
function myFunction(messager) {
    this.message = messager;
}
var instance = new myFunction("Hello");
document.write(instance.message);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a new instance and use that instead:

```
function myFunction(messager)
{
    this.message = messager;
}

var mf = new myFunction("Hello");
document.write(mf.message);
```

Answer (score 0):

There're already excellent answers so I'll just provide a simple one. This code creates an instance but doesn't store it anywhere:

```
new myFunction("Hello");
```